# vb.net error in parsing query of flexible column name

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, sql-server-ce

I'm having some problem in my query.

I'm trying to update a dataset if it exists in another datatable.

I'm having a datatable `ds1.table(0)` with 18 columns  with 2 primary keys, and datatable `ds2.table(0)` with a flexible number of rows.

If the column name of `ds1.table(0)` exists in the row of `ds2.table(0)` I would like to update my database.

```
 If rc1 > 0 Then
        For Each co As DataColumn In ds1.Tables(0).Columns
            Dim ColName As String = co.ColumnName

            If rc2 > 0 Then
                For Each ro As DataRow In ds2.Tables(0).Rows
                    Dim RoName As String = ro(0).ToString

                    If RoName.Contains(ColName) Then
                        Dim cmnd1 As SqlCeCommand

                        Try
                            con.Open()
                            Dim cry As String = "UPDATE serdate SET ['" & ColName & "'] = @date WHERE ((company = '" & Company & "') AND (number = '" & number & "'))"
                            cmnd1 = New SqlCeCommand(cry, con)
                            cmnd1.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter("@date", Now))
                            cmnd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
                            MsgBox("Update Success")
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            MsgBox("Query Error! " & ex.Message)
                        Finally
                             con.Close()
                        End Try
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

And I'm having some error.

The error is

> There was an error in parsing query: Column Name is not valid

Comment: do your column names actually contain the `'` character at the beginning and end?

Comment: debug and check value for ColName

Comment: Do you really want to check `RoName.Contains(ColName)`?  That would give you true if, for example, RoName was "Something" and ColName was "thing".  You probably want `=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is being caused by you trying to update a column which does not exist in the database. Have a look in the table definition to ensure the column actually exists. However, you're putting `'` around the column name which is not necessary when referring to a column and is most likely causing the error. Remove the `'` and use a valid column name to solve this.

On a bit of a unrelated note, your SQL query is vulnerable to SQL injection still. You should be using parameters for every variable you're putting into the query, like how you're putting in the date.